# Spring Boot test - MockHttpServletResponse getContentLength return 0 despite of content

Tags: java, httpresponse, servlet-3.0, spring-boot-test

I notice that in Spring Boot testing, the `getContentLength()` of `MockHttpServletResponse`, same as `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`, only reads the request header `"Content-Length"` to determine the returned value, but if in my test I don't set the header, it returns 0, ignoring whether there is any content.

```
@Then("xxxxx returns {string} and status code {int}")
public void xxxxx_returns_and_status_code(String result, Integer code) throws Exception {
    assertThat(this.results.getResponse().getContentType()).isEqualTo(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE); // <-- pass
    assertThat(this.results.getResponse().getStatus()).isEqualTo(code); // <-- pass

    System.out.println(this.results.getResponse().getContentLength()); // 0???
    System.out.println(this.results.getResponse().getContentAsString()); // the correct response

    assertThat(this.results.getResponse().getContentLength()).isNotEqualTo(0); // not pass, confusing
    getContentAsString()// pass
}
```

It, is standard, but somehow confusing.

To make the test pass, I have to do:

```
assertThat(this.results.getResponse().getContentAsString().length()).isNotEqualTo(0);
```

Why it was implemented this way?

Answer (score 0):

It MIGHT be the case, that the Integer conversion of the value HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH which is executed in the class leads to this behavior. This is the code setting the value for contentLength (which is initiated and resetted to 0):

```
else if (HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            setContentLength(value instanceof Number ? ((Number) value).intValue() :
                    Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
            return true;
}
```

Maybe getContentLengthLong will help your problem?

Check out the implementation on: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletResponse.java

Comment: No, it still returns 0. Actually the long method just return `contentLength` and the `getContentLength()` returns the same value casted to `long`. So they are the same.

Comment: Well have you debugged the library yet? The code can be found under the posted link.

Comment: I didn't debug into the lib because I cannot debug when I run a `.feature` file, is it true? I tried to sysout the `long` value and nothing. Still 0.

Comment: Hi @fl0w, now I just tried debug into the library, and find that the above line is never reached, because I haven't set the `Content-Length` header, it will never enter this `else if`. I also breakpoint on `setContentLength()` and `setContentLengthLong()`, and it never reached there, neither. I think some logic is lacking here; or, if I understand well, this method is very literal: reads the header and return the value, instead of returning the real value.

Comment: @WesternGun jup, that then makes absolute sense, if the setter is never callled then the value will not be available :) - congratulations on the analysis. I'd be interested in your solution :)

Comment: I mean, we should ask the dev team of Spring; maybe the intention was to literally read the header value and does no calculation(not adding information apart from the header info)......